# I am trying to email an image as an attachment without saving the image. I want to directly send the variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot use the local file-path because it's being denied and my school IT dude won't let me have access to my files using the root file path it just says Denied Permission.

Setup the attachment

```py
file_location = "H:/images"
filename1 = os.path.basename(file_location)
attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
part = MIMEBase('image', 'png', filename="screenshot.png")
part.set_payload(attachment.read())
```

What I want is instead of having to use a file location I want to use `pyscreenshot` image grab to grab an image and then send that image as an attachment.

Comment: So what's the issue? What's stopping you from doing what you are proposing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIMEBase did not require a actual local file path
and set_payload() will accept any compatible args passed in as payload
`pyscreenshot` itself relys on file save
but we can try to use a ByteIO object

try straightforward

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import io

img = ImageGrab.grab()
img_bytes = io.BytesIO()
img.save(img_bytes, format='PNG')

part = MIMEBase('image', 'png', filename="screenshot.png")
part.set_payload(img_bytes.getvalue())
```

for some unknown reason my python build refused to install PIL, so i am not able to debug the ImageGrab part

please comment if my code breaks